# TCP Socket: looping trough buffers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, networkstream

Im working on creating a loop of sending byte data from client to server for bigger data.
The buffer size is of 100 bytes and the `message` is of 4085 bytes.

The issue is that

CLIENT:

```
int bytesSent = 0;
        int bytesLeft = message.Length;
        Debug.WriteLine(bytesLeft);
        int offset = 0;
        byte[] encodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
            
            int curDataSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, bytesLeft);
            offset += curDataSize;
            networkstream.Write(encodedMessage, bytesSent, curDataSize);

            bytesSent += curDataSize;
            bytesLeft -= curDataSize;
        }
```

SERVER:

```
byte[] message = new byte[messageSize];


        int bytesRead = 0;
        int bytesLeft = messageSize;

        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
            int curDataSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, bytesLeft);
            if (client.Available < curDataSize)
                curDataSize = client.Available; //This saved me

            bytes = networkstream.Read(message, bytesRead, curDataSize);
            string messagestrr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, bytes);
            Debug.WriteLine(messagestrr);
            bytesRead += curDataSize;
            bytesLeft -= curDataSize;
        }
```

The issue is that it just keeps looping trough the first 100 bytes(aka the buffer).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        bytes = networkstream.Read(message, bytesRead, curDataSize);
```

You read into `message`, starting with position `bytesRead`. This means you append the new data to the message

```
        string messagestrr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, bytes);
        Debug.WriteLine(messagestrr);
```

But then you only print out the **first** `bytes` of the message, which are not the one actually Read in the previous line except for the first iteration. It likely should be

```
        string messagestrr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, bytesRead, bytes);
```

Comment: Brother, i spent two days going through this...You are a genius!